# numWeights corresponding to mnumVertices?

Tags: assimp

I have one issue left with ASSIMP DIRECT X C++ ANIMATION WITH SKELETON.

```
        for (UINT m = 0; m < currentMesh->mBones[k]->mNumWeights; m++) //verticer som påverkas
        {


            vertexVector[k].joints.x = currentMesh->mBones[k]->mWeights[m].mVertexId;
```

That code shows all vertices affected by a bone - k, inside an iteration.

All of these vertices must have the same vert ID since they are all affected by the same bone/joint.

The problem is, I need to make a list of every vertex and a list of every indice of a face, where I store position, UV, Normal etc.

The list that displays all of the vertices, is not in the same order obviously as the lists that displays all the vertices affected by each bone.

So how can I combine these lists?

"vertexVector"... etc is an example of a list with jointInfo that is corresponding to vertexID.
It has room for more places and another variable for the weight.

But that list doesn't work obviously.

What am I doing wrong with Assimp? Hope this was a clear post.

UPdate this is how i build the matrices: I don't know what is wrong.

```
                                      void jointTransform(float 
  timeInSeconds, std::vector<DirectX::XMMATRIX>& transformM, aiAnimation* 
    ani, UINT nrOfJoints, std::vector<joints>& jointInfo, const aiScene* 
   scenePtr)
  {


DirectX::XMMATRIX iD = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();

float ticksPerSecond = (float)ani->mTicksPerSecond;

if (ticksPerSecond == 0)
{
    ticksPerSecond = 30;
}

float timeInTicks = timeInSeconds * ticksPerSecond;

float animationTime = fmod(timeInTicks, (float)ani->mDuration);



readNodeHeiarchy(animationTime, scenePtr->mRootNode, iD, jointInfo, ani, 
 scenePtr);

transformM.resize(nrOfJoints);

for (UINT i = 0; i < transformM.size(); i++)
{
    transformM[i] = jointInfo[i].transformFinal;
}




   }
    void readNodeHeiarchy(float time, const aiNode* node, DirectX::XMMATRIX 
     parentMat, std::vector<joints>& jointInfo, aiAnimation* ani, const 
   aiScene* scenePtr)
   {
std::string nodeNameString = node->mName.data;



//Skapa en parentTransform från noden. Som sedan skickas in som parent 
  matris, första gången är det identitetsmatrisen.


aiMatrix4x4 nodeTransform = node->mTransformation;
DirectX::XMMATRIX combined;

combined = DirectX::XMMatrixSet(nodeTransform.a1, nodeTransform.a2, 
 nodeTransform.a3, nodeTransform.a4,
    nodeTransform.b1, nodeTransform.b2, nodeTransform.b3, nodeTransform.b4,
    nodeTransform.c1, nodeTransform.c2, nodeTransform.c3, nodeTransform.c4,
    nodeTransform.d1, nodeTransform.d2, nodeTransform.d3, 
   nodeTransform.d4);

const aiNodeAnim* joint = nullptr;
//Kolla om noden är ett ben.

for (UINT i = 0; i < ani->mNumChannels; i++)
{


    if (nodeNameString == ani->mChannels[i]->mNodeName.data)
    {
        joint = ani->mChannels[i];

    }


}
DirectX::XMMATRIX globalTransform = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();
//om den är ett ben så är joint inte längre nullptr, den blir det benet.
if (joint)
{



    DirectX::XMMATRIX S;
    DirectX::XMMATRIX R;
    DirectX::XMMATRIX T;

    //scale

    aiVector3D scaleV;
    calcLerpScale(scaleV, time, joint);
    S = DirectX::XMMatrixScaling(scaleV.x, scaleV.y, scaleV.z);


    //rotate
    aiQuaternion rotationQ;
    calcLerpRot(rotationQ, time, joint);

    DirectX::XMVECTOR q;

    q = DirectX::XMVectorSet(rotationQ.x, rotationQ.y, rotationQ.z, 
   rotationQ.w);

    R = DirectX::XMMatrixRotationQuaternion(q);

    //translate


    aiVector3D transV;

    calcLerpTrans(transV, time, joint);

    T = DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(transV.x, transV.y, transV.z);


    combined = S * R * T;

    globalTransform = combined * parentMat;

 }

 //DirectX::XMMATRIX globalTransform = combined * parentMat;







//if (jointInfo[jointInfo.size() - 1].name.C_Str() != nodeNameString)
//{



    for (UINT i = 0; i < jointInfo.size(); i++)
    {
        if (jointInfo[i].name.C_Str() == nodeNameString)
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("\n");
            OutputDebugStringA(jointInfo[i].name.C_Str());
            OutputDebugStringA("\n");

            aiMatrix4x4 off = jointInfo[i].offsetM;
            DirectX::XMMATRIX offset;
            offset = DirectX::XMMatrixSet(off.a1, off.a2, off.a3, off.a4,
                off.b1, off.b2, off.b3, off.b4,
                off.c1, off.c2, off.c3, off.c4,
                off.d1, off.d2, off.d3, off.d4);

            DirectX::XMMATRIX rootMInv;
            aiMatrix4x4 rootInv = scenePtr->mRootNode- 
   >mTransformation.Inverse();

            rootMInv = DirectX::XMMatrixSet(rootInv.a1, rootInv.a2, 
 rootInv.a3, rootInv.a4,
                rootInv.b1, rootInv.b2, rootInv.b3, rootInv.b4,
                rootInv.c1, rootInv.c2, rootInv.c3, rootInv.c4,
                rootInv.d1, rootInv.d2, rootInv.d3, rootInv.d4);


            jointInfo[i].transformFinal = offset * globalTransform * 
    rootMInv;


            break;
        }


    }


//}


for (UINT i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
{

    readNodeHeiarchy(time, node->mChildren[i], globalTransform, jointInfo, 
  ani, scenePtr);

}



 }
 void calcLerpScale(aiVector3D& scale, float aniTime, const aiNodeAnim* 
 joint)
 {

if (joint->mNumScalingKeys == 1)
{
    scale = joint->mScalingKeys[0].mValue;
    return;
}

UINT scaleInd = findIndexS(aniTime, joint);
UINT nextScale = scaleInd + 1;

assert(nextScale < joint->mNumScalingKeys);

float deltaTime = (float)joint->mScalingKeys[nextScale].mTime - 
  (float)joint->mScalingKeys[scaleInd].mTime;
float factor = (aniTime - (float)joint->mScalingKeys[scaleInd].mTime) / 
 deltaTime;

assert(factor >= 0.0f && factor <= 1.0f);

const aiVector3D& startScaleV = joint->mScalingKeys[scaleInd].mValue;
const aiVector3D& endScaleV = joint->mScalingKeys[nextScale].mValue;

//interpolate

aiVector3D Delta = endScaleV - startScaleV; // längden

scale = startScaleV + (factor * Delta); //gå ett antal steg beroende på 
 faktorn mellan start och slut.

scale.Normalize();




     }
  void calcLerpRot(aiQuaternion& rotation, float aniTime, const aiNodeAnim* 
  joint)
    {
if (joint->mNumRotationKeys == 1)
{
    rotation = joint->mRotationKeys[0].mValue;

    return;
}

UINT rotIndex = findIndexRot(aniTime, joint);
UINT nextRot = (rotIndex + 1);


assert(nextRot < joint->mNumRotationKeys);

float deltaTime = (float)joint->mRotationKeys[nextRot].mTime - 
 (float)joint->mRotationKeys[rotIndex].mTime;

float factor = (aniTime - (float)joint->mRotationKeys[rotIndex].mTime) / 
 deltaTime;

assert(factor >= 0.0f && factor <= 1.0f);


const aiQuaternion& StartRotationQ = joint->mRotationKeys[rotIndex].mValue;
const aiQuaternion& EndRotationQ = joint->mRotationKeys[nextRot].mValue;

aiQuaternion::Interpolate(rotation, StartRotationQ, EndRotationQ, factor);

rotation.Normalize();
    }
      void calcLerpTrans(aiVector3D& translation, float aniTime, const 
  aiNodeAnim* 
   joint)
      {
if (joint->mNumPositionKeys == 1)
{
    translation = joint->mPositionKeys[0].mValue;

    return;
}

UINT transIndex = findIndexT(aniTime, joint);
UINT nextTrans = (transIndex + 1);


assert(nextTrans < joint->mNumPositionKeys);

float deltaTime = (float)joint->mPositionKeys[nextTrans].mTime - 
   (float)joint->mPositionKeys[transIndex].mTime;

float factor = (aniTime - (float)joint->mPositionKeys[transIndex].mTime) / 
deltaTime;

assert(factor >= 0.0f && factor <= 1.0f);


const aiVector3D& startTransV = joint->mPositionKeys[transIndex].mValue;
const aiVector3D& endTransV = joint->mPositionKeys[nextTrans].mValue;

//interpolate

aiVector3D Delta = endTransV - startTransV;

translation = startTransV + (factor * Delta);

translation.Normalize();



    }
     UINT findIndexRot(float aniTime, const aiNodeAnim* joint)
   {

assert(joint->mNumRotationKeys > 0);

for (UINT i = 0; i < joint->mNumRotationKeys - 1; i++)
{
    if (aniTime < (float)joint->mRotationKeys[i + 1].mTime)
    {
        return i;
    }


}


assert(0);
}







        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "All of these vertices must have the same vert ID" - the vertex id's of the *k*:th bone, according to `mBones[k]->mWeights[..].mVertexId`, are indices to vertices influenced by this bone, and they are going to be different (otherwise there would be either redundancy of conflict).

You probably want to have bone indices and bone weights as part of the vertex definition for easy handling in a shader. Something like

```
struct vertex ( 
  vec3 pos;
  vec3 normal;
  float bone_weights[N]; // weights of bones influencing this vertex
  unsigned bone_indices[N]; // indices of bones influencing this vertex
}
std::vector<vertex> mesh_vertices;
```

Where N is the maximum number of influence bones per vertex. A common value is four, but this depends on the mesh your are importing.
Based on your example, a rough draft could be something like this:

```
// k:th bone of bones in currentMesh
  for (UINT m = 0; m < currentMesh->mBones[k]->mNumWeights; m++)
  {
    float bone_weight = currentMesh->mBones[k]->mWeights[m].mWeight;
    unsigned vertex_index = currentMesh->mBones[k]->mWeights[m].mVertexId;
    mesh_vertices[vertex_index].bone_weights[m] = bone_weight;
    mesh_vertices[vertex_index].bone_indices[m] = k;
  }
```

Here we've assumed that `mNumWeights = N`, but this needs to checked, as mentioned.

Comment: Yeah I had it wrong, but I think I figured out correct way of fetching the data. I am following Oglevs tutorial 38 but when I run it the verts just go to far away crap places and there is no animation just stretching and blobbing. I think the problem is where I build the matrices. Cus if I just do offset and inverse global then it's still the same problem.

Comment: I suggest you check out the complete source used in that tutorial, it works well as far as I know. It's a good idea also to avoid the additional complexity of animations and keyframe interpolation until you get the traversal for bind pose right (use mTransformation). Btw please mark the answer as accepted if it did answer your original question.